# How can I start with a fresh environment every time i reboot?

Tags: linux, kali-linux, gnu

Whenever I log back into my kali machine it seems that it saves a few things from my previous session. For example, I full-screened my terminal once and now every time I open my terminal it starts in full-screen on my second monitor. I was able to delete an old session that was bothering me before in the session and startup menu but now i'm not given that option. What can I do to clear the session and stop it from happening again?
[Screenshot of my session and startup screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8Ps9.png)

Answer (score 0):

> How can I start with a fresh environment every time I reboot  [Kali]?

**(A)** Turn the Save Session option OFF in the shutdown dialogue.  The option is still there for newest Kali version.

[image: Kali Shutdown Dialog]

..

**(B)** The other approach (which I use routinely in Linux and in Windows) is to close down apps before restarting.

...

**(C)** You might also try cleaning up updates, complete all updates and restart to see if that helps.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: I have this off already, still saves it.

Comment: My last comment was to turn Apps OFF prior to restart.  Normal apps do not restart on my Kali machine but if they do for you then close them first.

Comment: You might also try cleaning up updates. That helps in some situations.  Answer amended.